# How to solve for the angle $x$ ?($\tan(x)+ 4 \sin(x)=\sqrt 3$)

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

[image]

I have tried $\tan(x)+ 4 \sin(x)=\sqrt 3$ to make the notation simpler I will write $s:=\sin(x)$

$$4s +\frac{s}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}=\sqrt{3}$$
$$(\sqrt{3}-4s)^2 (1-s^2) = s^2$$
$$-16s^4 +8 \sqrt{3} x^3 +12s^2 -8\sqrt{3} s +3=0$$

needless to say solving this Quartic  equation will be too difficult and annoying so there must be some trick but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Why can it not just be difficult and annoying?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio because graphing the function $4\sin(x) +tan(x)-\sqrt 3$ the root in $(0,\pi/2)$ is $0.34906587$ which is if we divide pi by it we get $\frac{\pi}{0.34906587} =9$ so the angle is $20$ in degrees , since this is a $nice $ answer there must be some trick

Comment: A possibility is to use $t=\tan(x/2)$ substitution instead, you still get a quartic but contrary to yours it has $t=\sqrt{3}$ trivial solution and can be factored to a cubic. Now the cubic has all 3 real roots so if solvable this approach will still be painful.

Comment: How did you get $ \tan x + 4\sin x = \sqrt{3}$?

Comment: @marlite do you mean the question ?

Comment: @marlite from this telegram channel https://t.me/math_www it have a lot of great problems but most of them have a strange unmotivated solutions.

Comment: Wait sorry. Was $ \tan x + 4 \sin x =\sqrt{3}$ given in the question, or did you derive it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{gathered}
  \tan \left( x \right) + 4\sin \left( x \right) = \sqrt 3 \left( 1 \right) \hfill \\
   * x \ne \frac{\pi }{2} + k\pi ,k \in \mathbb{Z} \hfill \\
  \left( 1 \right) \Leftrightarrow 4\sin \left( x \right)\cos \left( x \right) + \sin \left( x \right) = \sqrt 3 \cos \left( x \right) \hfill \\
   \Leftrightarrow 2\sin \left( {2x} \right) = \sqrt 3 \cos \left( x \right) - \sin \left( x \right) = 2\cos \left( {x + \frac{\pi }{6}} \right) = 2\sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{3} - x} \right) \hfill \\
   \Leftrightarrow \sin \left( {2x} \right) = \sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{3} - x} \right) \Leftrightarrow \left[ \begin{gathered}
  2x = \frac{\pi }{3} - x + k2\pi  \hfill \\
  2x = \pi  - \left( {\frac{\pi }{3} - x} \right) + k2\pi  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.\left( {k \in \mathbb{Z}} \right) \hfill \\
   * 2x = \frac{\pi }{3} - x + k2\pi  \Leftrightarrow 3x = \frac{\pi }{3} + k2\pi  \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{\pi }{9} + k\frac{{2\pi }}{3} \hfill \\
   * 2x = \pi  - \left( {\frac{\pi }{3} - x} \right) + k2\pi  \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{{2\pi }}{3} + k2\pi  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$

Comment: $x$ is acute in this rectangle triangle the spurious solutions should be eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

Using @zwin's suggestion, $x=2 \tan ^{-1}(t)$ and taking into account that $t=\sqrt 3$ is a solution, the equation becomes
$$\frac {t-\sqrt 3}{1-t^4}\Big(  \sqrt{3} \left(t-\sqrt{3}\right)^3 +6 \left(t-\sqrt{3}\right)^2-8\Big)$$
Let $t=(u+\sqrt 3)$ and solve the cubic
$$\sqrt{3}\,u^3 +6 u^2-8=0$$ which shows three real roots since $\Delta=1728$.

Using the trigonometric method
$$u_k=\frac{4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}-\frac{2 \pi 
   k}{3}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\qquad \text{for} \qquad k=0,1,2$$ that is to say
$$t_k=\frac{4 \cos \left(\frac{1}{9} (\pi -6 \pi  k)\right)+1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$t_0=\frac{1+4 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}\qquad\qquad t_1=\frac{1-4 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}\qquad\qquad t_2=\frac{1-4 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{9}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}$$ that is to say
$$x_0=\frac{7 \pi }{9}\qquad\qquad \color{red}{x_1=\frac{ \pi }{9}}\qquad\qquad x_2=-\frac{5 \pi }{9}$$

Answer (score 1):

I often use the tan-half-angle substitution of $t = \tan \frac{x}{2}$ which results in the following:

$$\begin{aligned} \sin x = \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \\ \cos x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \end{aligned}$$

The equation now is just a rational polynomial

$$ \frac{2 t}{1-t^2} +4 \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} = \sqrt{3}$$

and it has 4 solutions

$$ t = \begin{cases}
  \sqrt{3} \\
  \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3} - \tfrac{4 \sqrt{3} \sin \tfrac{\pi}{18}}{3} \\
  \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3} + \tfrac{4 \sqrt{3} \cos \tfrac{\pi}{9}}{3} \\
  \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3} - \tfrac{4 \sqrt{3} \cos \tfrac{2\pi}{9}}{3}
\end{cases}$$

and then recover $x$ with $$x =2 \arctan t$$